# failed to construct 'Worker' even worker script on same domain with the script which initialize the worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I initialized worker by

```
var base_ur = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/';
var search_worker = new Worker(base_url+'assets/js/search-worker.js');

search_worker.onmessage = function(e){

}
```

and even do the web worker resides on the same domain with the script which initialized the web worker script it still gives me this error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at
>   'https://www.mywebsite.com/assets/js/search-worker.js' cannot be
>   accessed from origin 'https://www.mywebsite.com'.
>       at https://www.mywebsite.com/assets/js/search.js

any ideas, help please?